# Python - Search for match in string

Tags: python, csv, variables, wildcard

Just trying to pick up python and use it, but I am having a headache. I have a log file I want to search for specific usernames, but the string that is produced is something along the lines of the below (sensitive bits removed);

```
MSWinEventLog<009>5<009>Security<009>1157464<009>Mon Apr 24 00:37:27 2017<009>4672<009>Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing<009><009>N/A<009>Audit Success<009>Domain-Controller<009>17548<009>Special privileges assigned to new logon.<013><010><013><010>Subject:<013><010><009>Security ID:<009><009>S-9-8-21-9576767673-22488686304-465465468911-1103<013><010><009>Account Name:<009><009>MyUserNameSearch<013><010><009>Account Domain:<009><009>DomainName<013><010><009>Logon ID:<009><009>0x2176ca6b<013><010><013><010>Privileges:<009><009>SeSecurityPrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeBackupPrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeRestorePrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeDebugPrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeLoadDriverPrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeImpersonatePrivilege<013><010><009><009><009>SeEnableDelegationPrivilege
```

In this is the username, how can I search for that? So far I have this

```
import csv
import re

username = input('Enter Username\n')
regex = re.compile('.username.')
with open('C:/Path/To/Log/File.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    logreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in logreader:
        for field in row:
            if field == username:
                print('found it')
```

How can I introduce a wildcard at the start and beginning of the username?

All I want the script to do is search for a given username and return the rows where the username is found. If I can get this working then I'll look at how to return the rows.

Comment: Sorry not well explained after reading this back, I want to search a csv file for a specific username ,per row. However the username is buried in a field in the csv file, the field containing the username is one long string. The example starting MsWinEventLog, I am trying to search for the username in that string

Comment: MsWinEventLog is not the username, that is part of the string containing the username. Have a look at my question that contains the example string. In there for example is MyUserNameSearch (pretend username), how can I search for that with everything else around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute your `if field == username` line by `if username in field`.

This will always return `True` if your `username` string is `in` the `field` string.

---

```
field = 'abcd1234'
username = 'cd12'

if username in field:
    print('found it')

>>> found it
```

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like that it has worked first time!